# components inside rows disappearing when filtering data angular ag gird

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ag-grid, cellrenderer

I have an ag grid with several custom components for each column, the component are showing but whenever I filter the data the component disappears, for example:
[the component inside the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX9rI.png)

to filter I use an input with a filtering function:

```html
<data-grid [rowData]="filteredData(searchInput.query)"/>
```

the data-grid selector contains a regular ag-grid-angular component:

```html
<ag-grid-angular 
    style="width: 100%; height: 350px;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" />
```

after filtering the custom component inside the row disappears:
[no component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtGLr.png)

what could be the problem? Thanks in advance

I was expecting for the components inside the rows to appear normally, tried looking for re-rendering in the docs but no luck

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your filteredData(searchInput.query) method is causing this issue, but I'd need to see at least these two component's typescript files to tell what's going on.

Comment: [FlagCode Component](https://pastebin.com/iRJe3R6H) used inside the row, [filteredData function](https://pastebin.com/aEyyPybX)

Comment: Thanks for sharing that.  Since this is happening after filtering, have you used the debugger and set a breakpoint to watch the data as it's being filtered?  That might give you a clue as to what's going on here.

Comment: I didn't, I'm re-reading the docs maybe I can find something

Comment: Definitely familiarize yourself with the debugger tool offered through Chrome.  It's very powerful.